# How to show elements of a list from selected head to tail in racket

Tags: list, racket, member

I am trying to create a function that allows users to have to input 2 values which will then show the elements of the list starting from the specific head to the specific tail. So far I have the basic code:

```lisp
(define fruits (λ (n) (member n '( "Apple" "Pear"
                       "Peach" "pineapple"
                      "dragon fruit" "blue berry" "mango"
                       "strawberry"))))
```

so user can get for example:

```lisp
(fruits "Pear")
'("Pear" "Peach" "pineapple" "dragon fruit" "blue berry" "mango" "strawberry")
```

I want the list to stop after a specific value that the user inputted. for instance peach to blue berry. I tried various things such as filters, sorts, range, in-range, strings, sequence, etc but still fail. Could anyone please explain to me how do this.

Comment: Tip: To remove the trailing part you can: reverse the list with `reverse`, remove the first part, reverse again.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Do you know how to read input from user? Is this homework, so you are limited somehow (allowed subset of language / some functions you can't use), or can you use any DrRacket function or library?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `member` to get the tail of the list starting with the value you're interested in, but I prefer using [`dropf`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._dropf%29%29) for that part, as it's more indicative of what you want to do (Plus when there's no match it returns an empty list, not `#f`, which simplifies things). There's also [`takef`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._takef%29%29), which returns the head of the list until an element makes a predicate return false, but since it doesn't include that element, it won't quite work. It's easy to make an inclusive version, though, which can then be combined with `dropf` to get a list in the inclusive range of two values:

```lisp
#lang racket/base

(require racket/function racket/list)

;;; Returns the elements of a list up to and including the first one that
;;; pred? returns false for.
(define (takef/inclusive lst pred?)
  (for/list ([elem (in-list lst)]
             #:final (not (pred? elem)))
    elem))

;;; Returns a list of elements from the first one equal to first to the
;;; first one equal to last
(define (extract-list lst first last #:test [=? equal?])
  (takef/inclusive (dropf lst (negate (curry =? first))) (negate (curry =? last))))
```

Examples:

```lisp
> (extract-list '( "Apple" "Pear" "Peach" "pineapple" "dragon fruit" "blue berry" "mango" "strawberry")
                "Peach" "blue berry")
'("Peach" "pineapple" "dragon fruit" "blue berry")
> (extract-list '( "Apple" "Pear" "Peach" "pineapple" "dragon fruit" "blue berry" "mango" "strawberry")
                "peach" "blue berry" #:test string-ci=?)
'("Peach" "pineapple" "dragon fruit" "blue berry")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to write a 'primitive' version of this, without using things like `for/list` and so on, an approach is to do this:

1. Look at the list:

   - is it empty?  If it is either the answer is the empty list or it is an error;
   - is the first element of the list the start element?  If it is start (2) with this list and an empty list;
   - otherwise do (1) with the rest of the list.
2. Look at the first element of the list you now have:

   - is it empty? This is either an error or the result is the reverse of the list you are accumulating;
   - Is the first element the same as the end element you are looking for?  if it is then the answer is the reverse of the result of consing his element onto the accumulator;
   - otherwise do (2) with the rest of the list and a cons of the first of the list and the accumulator.

Step (1) is implemented by the `member` function but I'll just implement it directly.

So here is that algorithm as a function. This version assumes that you don't want errors, but instead returns a second value to tell you whether it succeeded or not.

```
(define (take-between l from to (test? eqv?))
  (let find-tail ([tail l])
    ;; search down tails of l for from
    (cond
      [(null? tail)
       ;; never found from
       (values tail #f)]
      [(test? (first tail) from)
       ;; we found it
       (let take-tail ([remaining-tail tail]
                       [accum '()])
         ;; search down tails of tail for to, accumulating things into accum
         ;; on the way
         (cond
           [(null? remaining-tail)
            ;; never found to
            (values (reverse accum) #f)]
           [(test? (first remaining-tail) to)
            ;; found to
            (values (reverse (cons (first remaining-tail) accum)) #t)]
           [else
            ;; haven't yet found to
            (take-tail (rest remaining-tail)
                       (cons (first remaining-tail) accum))]))]
      [else
       ;; haven't yet found from
       (find-tail (rest tail))])))
```

Now

```
> (take-between '(1 2 3 4 5) 2 4)
'(2 3 4)
#t
> (take-between '(1 2 3 4 5) 2 10)
'(2 3 4 5)
#f
> (take-between '(1 2 3 4 5) 10 20)
'()
#f
```